# GCE Required 'compute.zones.list' permission for 'projects/someproject'

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I've created project in GCP. Then I created service account with `Compute Admin` role. After that, I enabled `Compute Engine API` for my project, but can't work with instances:

```
#gcloud compute instances list  
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.list) Some requests did not succeed:
- Required 'compute.zones.list' permission for 'projects/someproject'
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first time I created a service account "cloud66" in the Google test period. Most likely, this affected the access rights. Then I switched billing from a test period to a paid one. I deleted and recreated the cloud66 service account in the "APIs & Services -> Credentials" section. But there was an access policy for "cloud66" with the role of "ComputeAdmin" in the "IAM" section. When I deleted the access policy from the "IAM" section and recreated the service account, the problem was resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Check that the service account you are using to run that command has the proper [Compute Engine role](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/iam#compute.admin). You can do this here: IAM & admin > IAM.

-- UPDATE --

For checking that the [service account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts#creating) has the correct permissions run these commands in the Cloud Shell:

`$ gcloud iam service-accounts keys create key.json \
--iam-account new-sa@some-project-name.iam.gserviceaccount.com`

The above command will create and download the key for this service account in a JSON format.

`$ gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding some-project-name \
--member serviceAccount:new-sa@some-project-name.iam.gserviceaccount.com \
--role=roles/compute.admin`

This command will assign compute.admin role to new-sa service account.

`$ gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=key.json`

`$ gcloud compute instances list`

And with these, impersonate **new-sa** service account using the key.json file already downloaded and execute the corresponding command to list the instances in **some-project-name** project.
If this is successful then the issue is somewhere else.

Comment: It has ComputeAdmin role. I am trying add GCE to cloud66 from this doc: https://help.cloud66.com/rails/how-to-guides/clouds/cloud-gce.html#generate-gce-api-keys

Comment: If you have enabled the [Compute Engine API](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/enable-api#enabling_an_api) and provided the right permissions to the SA (check update) I would try downloading a [new key](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-account-keys#creating_service_account_keys).

Comment: Thank  you! your answer helped me to find and resolve the issue. Because a new Service Account with another name works without any problem. I have solved the problem after i remove policy from IAM for cloud66 and then i recreated it(early i removed clud66 only from Service Account).

Comment: You're welcome @Ninja xD